# Unable to find out existing element using jQuery length

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket

I am using [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) to update/display some users based on search from a text box, i.e. chosen result from text will be displayed in multiselect, as per my application requirement. Unselecting an option will remove that value from multiselect and rebuilds. I am using wicket framework to display this multiselect as shown below -

```
private PaletteListChoice<T> addSelectedEntities(...) {
    final PaletteListChoice<T> result = new PaletteListChoice<T>(id, model, choicesModel, renderer, this) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)
        {
            String jsSelectedField = "var idSelector = '" + getMarkupId() + "';\n"
                    + "var idSelectorUL = jQuery('#' + idSelector +'UL');\n"
                    + "if(idSelectorUL.length) {\n" // if idSelectorUL present, don't create bootstrap-multiselect again
                    + "} else {\n" // if idSelectorUL not present, then create bootstrap-multiselect again
                    + "MultiSelect.setMultiSelect(idSelector, false);\n" // custom code to display bootstrap multiselect, similar to $('#id').multiselect();
                    + "}\n";

            response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript(jsSelectedField);
        }
    };
    parent.add(result);
    return result;
}
```

Now, *my problem is though idSelectorUL (for e.g. selectddUL) is present, I am getting **idSelectorUL.length as '0'***. I am rebuilding multiselect as soon as option is deleted and due to the above problem, I am getting two multiselects (length returns 0 and wicket creates multiselect option)

Any issue with my code or any other way to identify an UL present based on id using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `setOutputMarkupId(true);` on your component?

Does that component exist on the page on load, or does that component get added via ajax?  If so you should move your javascript from the renderHead, into a Behavior that is attached to the component itself.

Comment: I am not calling `setOutputMarkupId(true)`. 

While adding new report, component gets added via ajax, while editing/copying , Component exists on page load. Yes, I was thinking of moving JS code from renderHead to AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. Will update later.